# is there something like httpPost in k8s

Tags: post, kubernetes

I know that k8s have *readynessProbe* with *httpGet* method to check if service ready to work or not.
Is there something like *httpPost* method to run *POST* request to /api/postService with some body and check return code?
Or some *tricky* way to do it in yaml file.

Answer (score 3):

Can be done by running curl as an exec readinessProbe:

```
readinessProbe:
  exec:
    command:
    - "curl" 
    - "-X POST"
    - "-f"
    - "http://localhost/api/postService"
```

Of course you'd need to make sure to install *curl* in the Docker image that packages your service.

Comment: Sorry for stupid question, but what is the **service image**? Is this thing like docker service(as mongo for app) or I have to install it to the same image I run? Can you point me to documentation of service, I spent about an hour looking for this..  Cannot understand your point. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I guess my wording got you confused. What I meant by 'service image' is the Docker image that packages your service (the same one you are trying to create a readinessProbe for). So yes - install curl in the same image you run.

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I think this way is more reliable.

```
readinessProbe:
    exec:
      command:
      - sh
      - -c
      - >-
          curl -X POST http://localhost/api/postService -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{\"test\": \"OK\"}'
```